# how to get print of ssh user logged in by password?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, login, logging

I want to know if it is possible to get the hash key fp from the ssh diaries for the ssh user login with a password, not a key. I see public key login keyprints recorded in the file, but no passwd  logins fp. I'm looking to see if someone has logged into my account with my pwd without me knowing. Does it leave a unique footprint for each device? I tried verbose logging with the ssh demons but I don't see anything written to identify a user login with keyboard passwords besides ip address. That wouldn't work for me the because ip address is changed often by router. Thanks for your help You have a good weekend

Comment: Logging into SSH without a key would not have a fingerprint in record because passphrases don't have a fingerprint, only SSH keys do. Why not just enforce key-only logins, as it's generally more secure than passphrases, especially when the key is encrypted with a passphrase?

Comment: The reason I have a password is because sometimes I want to log in with a new device that I have not configured with the keys. Sometimes I want to try another. Is it possible to search for the mac address? If not, I'll give up on it.

Comment: _(@user1686 Answered that question below)_ The most convenient way I've found to address new devices is to use a GPG key as the SSH key. To do so, create a primary GPG RSA:4096 key that can only `S`[ign] and `C`[ertify] _(it's only purpose is to sign and certify subkeys)_, then create three RSA:2048 subkeys, one each for `S`, `E`[ncryption], and `A`[uthentication], with the Authentication key doubling as an SSH key. I maintain two physical copies of my primary and subkeys, one on my PC and another on a Yubikey 5C that I use for SSH.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if it is possible to get the hash key fp from the ssh diaries for the ssh user login with a password, not a key. I see public key login keyprints recorded in the file, but no passwd logins fp

There's no "hash key fingerprint" *because there is no key.* That's literally what it means to use a password to authenticate instead of a key.

Common security advice is to simply *disable* password authentication and require all clients to use keys or similar methods.

> Does it leave a unique footprint for each device? I tried verbose logging with the ssh demons but I don't see anything written to identify a user login with keyboard passwords besides ip address.

No, it doesn't. The IP address:port is all you have.

And the date/time, of course. If you see a login happened when you were asleep, then that's suspicious. But it doesn't say which device did it.

You could also look at the SSH client's version string (the one which says `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH-etc` in highly verbose levels) – of course, all Debian 10 clients look the same, all Arch clients look the same, but you can still distinguish an actual /usr/bin/ssh (OpenSSH) from various automated brute-forcing bots (which often use Java or Python SSH modules and this is reflected in the version string they send).